# How to calculate my program difference in python

Tags: python-2.7

so I send out two commands and through a communication port and a two strings are returned to me like this: `accel x y z: -181 -7962 668` and `accel x y z: -182 -7968 675`. 
I need to calculate the difference and make sure they’re not more than 10. 
I then used the `re.search` n  regex to group that string according like this: `re.search('(-?\d{2,3})\s(-?\d{3,4})\s(-?\d{2,3})$', log[1])`

Here’s what I have so far, my python script keeps failing and I don’t know why. If anyone can help it’ll be much appreciated.

Send a command through a communication channel and get back:
`accel x y z: -181 -7962 668` and `accel x y z: -182 -7968 675`.

```
accelSample = re.search('(-?\d{2,3})\s(-?\d{3,4})\s(-?\d{2,3})$', log[1])    
accelSample2 = re.search('(-?\d{2,3})\s(-?\d{3,4})\s(-?\d{2,3})$', log[1])

if accelSample:

    x_avg = int(accelSample.group(1) - accelSample2.group(1))
    y_avg = int(accelSample.group(2) - accelSample2.group(2))
    z_avg = int(accelSample.group(3) - accelSample2.group(3))
    #calculating difference from group 1
    if abs(x_avg) < 10 or abs(y_avg) < 10 or abs(z_avg) < 10:
        return Test.TestResult.PASS

else:
    return Test.TestResult.FAIL
```

Comment: You parse the same string two times: log[1]. Also how do you know that there is only one space between the tokens? Try \s+ . Last but not least, try printing the parsed groups and see what is getting there.

Comment: I parsed two strings however they are the same, the command sent are at different samples n the numbers generated are at random. I did however utilize the \s+ for additional whitespaces that I wasn't accounting for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- each regex match is a string, and has to be cast to an `int` separately
- if *any* x,y,z value is > 10 from the other sample, then it fails. Original code was too lenient
- fields tend to have random numbers of spaces -- new regex allows this

### source

```
import re

sample_pat = re.compile(
    '(-?\d{2,3})\s+'
    '(-?\d{3,4})\s+'
    '(-?\d{2,3})$'
    )

def check(log):
    s1 = sample_pat.search(log[0])
    s2 = sample_pat.search(log[1])

    for n in range(1, 3+1):
        if abs( int(s1.group(n)) - int(s2.group(n)) ) > 10:
            return 'fail'
    return 'pass'

print check(['accel x y z: -181 -7962 668',
             'accel x y z: -182 -7968 675'
         ])
```

### output

```
pass
```